# deck.gl react base map appears jittery and shaky

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react

I'm going through the tutorial to get started with deck.gl working in react.
I managed to get the underlying map to appear.
But I get an issue where the react page is visually shaky and jittery (hurts the eyes just looking at it), I had this happen also in the process of development on one of the error messages but it went away.

Here is the code for It's mostly based on
https://deck.gl/docs/get-started/using-with-react

But I also had a look at and the dependencies used here
https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/an-introduction-into-deck-gl-f5c8ae84d9a5

Here is app.js

```
import React from "react";
import DeckGL from "@deck.gl/react";
import {LineLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';
import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';

const MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = <removed token>;

// Viewport settings
const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: -122.41669,
  latitude: 37.7853,
  zoom: 13,
  pitch: 0,
  bearing: 0
};

// Data to be used by the LineLayer

const data = [
  {sourcePosition: [-122.41669, 37.7853], targetPosition: [-122.41669, 37.781]}
];

function App({data}) {
  const layers = [
    new LineLayer({id: 'line-layer', data})
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
      layers={layers}
    >
      <StaticMap mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} />
    </DeckGL>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone, know why the app goes jittery what have or could I have missed?

I couldn't find anything on it.

It seems like it works in firefox and edge just not chrome, but I need it to work in chrome.  No extensions are enabled.

Comment: Hi, I also encountered the same problem. Did you solve this problem later?

Comment: Nope unfortunately not